# How to I view the contents of a database in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

I created a simple database table using the entity frame work....

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var db = new DatabaseContext1();
        db.PeopleTable1.Add(new Person { FirstName = "Joe", LastName = "Bloggs0" });
        db.SaveChanges(); 
    }
}

public class DatabaseContext1 : System.Data.Entity.DbContext  {
    public DbSet<Person> PeopleTable1 { get; set; }
}

public class Person {
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public String FirstName { get; set; }
    public String LastName { get; set; }
}
```

I believe there is a graphical viewer in the Server Explorer panel or somewhere where I can view the DB tables as a 2D grid but I cant seem to find it.

UPDATE:

What my server explorer looks like..

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is called Server Explorer and it is usually stacked with Solution Explorer. If you cannot see it, you can go to the View menu and select Server Explorer.

UPDATE:

First things first:

Have you checked the Web.Config (or App.Config if not a web project) for connection strings and where they are pointing to?

Then you need to create a connection to the database server your connection string is pointing to. You can right click on the Data Connections in Server Explorer and click new connection. After that just follow the wizard. Your database should appear once you have created the connection.

Comment: I thought it was in Server explorer, but I cant seem to find the database here. Do I need to configure the project or add more code than I have shown for it to appear?

Comment: ok thanks, I looked in app.config and there is no none there. This must be the problem. I will read up on how to create one. Do I also need to install sql or something?